# Scrolling NSScrollView's documentView past CGFloat range

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, infinite-scroll

I'm running into a problem in 32bit builds with NSScrollView scrolling past the 24 bits of CGFloat (float in 32bit, double in 64bit builds).

Is there any way to specify a 'Screen Sized' (ie. float range) documentView and an int64 offset (or something similar), so that my drawing of the documentVisibleRect is always using valid coordinates?

...or am I missing something really basic here?

Also (just curious), how would scroll infinitely for something like a real world map zoomed into street level?

Comment: For the map you'd probably just do what Google Maps does and allow panning via the mouse and gestures only. Google Maps doesn't have scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of building 32 bit applications as 64 bit. You can read about here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html

However it might be a good idea to reconsider what you're actually trying to do. Having such a large scroll means the documentView is really huge and takes up a lot of memory. Also I fail to see how this design is a positive thing for the users as they would probably need a lifetime to scroll to the edge of their document. You might consider implementing something that's called *infinite scrolling*. There's a SO question about this here: [Scrollbars for Infinite Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733443/scrollbars-for-infinite-document)